# Adding Single-sign-on to GMail API authorization

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, single-sign-on, gmail-api

I have successfully created a python web-app on Google App Engine that interacts with the Gmail API. What I would like to get now, is that when that the permissions are given, my app also creates a user account to which the user can login with their Google Account. This would prevent the user to having to type in another password for my app.

To summarize, current workflow is:
1. User creates account by typing in email and password
2. User authorizes GMail access

What I would like to get is:
1. User connects Google Account and therewith gets an account and authenticates GMail access

What would be the best way to do this?

My current code for the google API looks something like below. Straight from the Google example here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id='your_client_id',
  client_secret='your_client_secret',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
    http = decorator.http()
    # Call the service using the authorized Http object.
    request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
    response = request.execute(http=http)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was the exact tutorial for what I was trying to do :https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Comment: is there an example of this in swift

Answer (score 1):

1. To access Google API's first you have to register in developer console. check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)
2. I understand your flow is, user logins with gmail id and password and user has to give access to your app. While using oauth flow, if you select 'access_type'='offline' in your code, it helps to access information even when user if offline. For this you need [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).
3. In your developers console, you have to activate all the API's that your application is going to use.
4. In the above mentioned Oauth link you can check how to handle authorization requests, how to authenticate user.
5. If you want to go with [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), then don't forget to do [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).
6. While deciding on the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), use readonly scope if your application is not writing any information to the user account.

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python) for Gmail API sample client code in python.